# How to return response from Rails ActionController in parallel with long-running process?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I primarily use Node for backend services but maintain a Rails 3.2 API with Ruby 1.9.3. Recently we realized that in some corner cases our `FoosController#create` controller method was taking so long that the clients were timing out before receiving a response. I have something like

```
def create
  if check_for_bad(params) # Validation step
    return bad_params_error # Return 400 error
  end

  Foo.create(params) # Need to move this to a parallel thread

  output = { status: 200, message: 'OK' }
  return render json:output
end
```

The client doesn't need to know about any errors after the initial params check, so I want to return the response before running `Foo#create` but I do need to pass `params` to that method. I've tried putting it in an `after_filter` method (I got `undefined method` when trying `after_action`).

It seems like this should be easy, probably using fibers or a gem that builds on it, but I'm not familiar enough with what's available to make sure I'm doing something that works without causing more problems than I'm solving.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Look at sidekiq`: https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq

Comment: Thanks @BroiSatse -- Sidekiq does the trick. If you want to answer with some more detail I'll approve it. Otherwise I'll write up what worked tomorrow in case anyone else has a similar issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @BroiSatse mentioned, I'd recommend doing this in the background with Sidekiq. The guides on Sidekiq give the overall setup, but in this case you'd have to change a little bit of your thinking on what it means to create a Foo.

You would immediately create a Foo with a state of "pending" or something, and then pass your params and the created Foo id to a background worker, which would do the hard work. If everything succeeds there, you would update your Foo be "completed" or "ready".

To do the Foo creation background work, you would create a worker:

```
# app/workers/CreateFooWorker.rb
class CreateFooWorker
  include Sidekiq::Worker

  def perform(foo_id, params)
    if foo = Foo.find(foo_id) && foo.update_attributes(params)
      foo.update_attribute(:state, "ready")
    end
  end
end

# Change create to immediately create a foo without the params
# and then actually build the real foo with params in the background
def create
  if check_for_bad(params) # Validation step
    return bad_params_error # Return 400 error
  end

  foo = Foo.create(state: "pending") # Just create with a pending state...
  CreateFooWorker.perform_async(foo.id, params) # Now do the real work in the background

  # You're going to want to retun the foo json here
  # because your client will need to hold onto the
  # foo.id and query the server for when the foo is "ready"
  return render json: foo.to_json, status: created
end
```